# Configure script to write content of config.log into stdout and/or stderr

Tags: docker, maven, github, automake

A bit complicated case: I'm trying to debug configure script which is run by Maven, which runs inside Docker container, which is run by GitHub Action. It fails and asks me to look into `config.log`. Of course, I don't have access to that `config.log` (I should probably somehow take it out of container and save into GitHub actions artifacts, but that's too long...) Is there a way to make it write that output just to stdout/stderr instead of config.log?

Comment: The original tags (C, C++, Automake) are mostly inappropriate, IMO.  Docker, GitHub, Maven would be more relevant than either C or C++, I think.

Comment: ok, thank you for putting better tags!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to print contents of the file

Try this in the workflow:

```
steps:
  - name: Read config.log
    id: configlog
    uses: juliangruber/read-file-action@v1
    with:
      path: /path/to/config.log
  - name: Echo config.log
    run: echo "${{ steps.configlog.outputs.content }}"
```

Comment: If you have `run` executing shell commands, why not just `cat config.log`?

Comment: I believe `cat` is also possible, did not test it. This example is from my real project and it works, not sure for 100% why this way was chosen.

Comment: This will unconditionally print out a file that is typically several thousand lines long. instead it should only be run if the `configure` job failed (which most likely will fail the `maven` job as well, so should be pretty easy to detect)